# Event to detect change of an HTML5 number control in Webkit/Chrome?

Tags: javascript, forms, html, google-chrome

HTML5 gives us some new input elements to play with, such as `<input type=number>`. This renders (in Chrome) as a textbox with two cycle buttons inside the textbox, for incrementing and decrementing the numeric value inside the box.

For a personal hobby project, I'm using this control. However, I'm stuck with one issue:

Is there a way to detect the value being changed using a javascript event? I had expected the `onChange` event to fire, but no such luck. Also, `onClick` only triggers when the textbox content is clicked, not when the cycle buttons are clicked.

Any ideas? (apart from: hey, it's HTML5 Forms, don't expect anything to work yet!)

**Edit:** As mikerobi points out below, the onChange event does fire as soon as the element loses focus. Still not quite what I'm looking for, so other comments and suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Result of the bugreport: Won't Fix, because the `input` event is fired when those buttons are pressed. It's part of the HTML5 spec. So problem solved, thanks to mikerobi's sugestion to file the report.

Comment: Does this work for you in Safari? I'm using Safari 5.0.3 (mac) and the input event is fired only when I change the number in the text box, not when I click on those buttons.

Comment: Safari v5.0.4 does not fire a `change` event even when you blur the input, and does not fire an `input` event when clicking on the spinners. Seems to be a Safari bug all around with `<input type="number">`.

Comment: Note, however, that the behavior is correct in the latest WebKit nightly builds, so _eventually_ this fix should make its way into Safari.

Answer (score 2):

The `onChange` event gets fired when when the box loses focus, but you probably already know that.

The HTML5 specifies that a number input should be a text box or spinner control, but the spec does not appear to have any guidelines for how a spinner should look or behave, leaving those decisions up to the browser vendors.

It appears that in the Mac Safari, the spin buttons do respond to click events, you might want to file a Chrome bug report, I suspect it was just an oversight.

Comment: Hi Mikerobi - yeah, should have added that I found the change-on-blur thing already.. thanks for mentioning it though. I'll go file that bug report, thanks!

Comment: Which Safari are you using? Mine (5.0.2 on Windows) doesn't support the number type at all, and renders it as a plain textbox :/

Answer (score 2):

$.click() works fine. If you click and hold, it doesn't until you release.