# Is there any jQuery .change realtime alternative?

Tags: jquery, forms, events, event-handling

I want something to happen right after change has been made in input field, not after this input has been unfocused. Is there any alternative?

[DEMO HERE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/b5UZN/)

**UPDATE** it should be also working for types where user doesn't have to actually click the button in the keyboard (like HTML5 input types=number/date)

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060782/event-to-detect-change-of-an-html5-number-control-in-webkit-chrome

Comment: Reading your answers makes me feel like there is no 100% working alternative

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The actual event changes with the type of the control. I put together some examples:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function callback() { alert($(this).val()); }
    $('input[type=number]').on('input',callback);
    $('input[type=date]').on('input',callback);
    $('input[type=text]').on('keyup',callback);
});
```

NOTE: If you use CTRL+V to paste text, the `keyup` event might fire *twice*.

NOTE2: Right click -> Paste won't be recognized. `paste` event won't help you either, because it fires *before* the text is updated.

Comment: Why can't I use on('input') for text field as well? It seems like correct answer

Comment: At least you could set a timeout on `paste` - ugly, but it would presumably work.

Answer (score 2):

The keyup event occurs when a keyboard key is released.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#i1').on('keyup',function() {
              alert('Changed');
    });
```

[`.keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)

Comment: Beware that `keyup` won't catch all cases, eg. Right-click / Paste.

Answer (score 1):

if its a text field then you would need to use `.keyup`

since you are wanting for html5 field try the `.click`

should work for the `number` field not sure about the `date` ones.

Answer (score 0):

Use on("keyup") here is demo.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/b5UZN/1/

Comment: ok thx, but I want it to be working for input type=number for examle

Answer (score -1):

Something like that?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#i1').on('keyup',function() {
                  alert('Change has been recognised!');
        });
        $('#i1').on('paste',function() {
                  alert('Change has been recognised!');
        });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/b5UZN/4/)

Comment: _'not after this input has been unfocused.'_ ... yet, _'The blur event is sent to an element when it loses focus.'_

Comment: ok corrected answer @GrantThomas

Comment: `paste` fires before the text is updated (`val()` still shows old text)

Comment: use a timeout of miliseconds for example
$('#i1').on('paste',function() {
                 setTimeout( alert('Change has been recognised!   '+$(this).val()),50);
        });